# How to enable CORS in gremlin server janusgraph

Tags: cors, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

We have a gremlin server powered by JanusGraph running and accessible with its domain URL, now since the CORS is not enabled by default, it rejects all gremlin queries over HTTP (i.e. /gremlin/?gremlin=g.V().....) from other domains.

Is there any config for enabling CORS?

found the same was asked on gitter (https://gitter.im/janusgraph/janusgraph?at=5fca30cc5be1fb21c5fb0d94) but the answered SO reference (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64799738/allow-cors-on-janusgraph-http-server) page is not found at the moment.

It very common usecase and believe there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

We were looking at some specific configs that can be enabled in gremlin-server yaml config but with no such configs available, we found that [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.HttpGremlinEndpointHandler](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/a7181e23421818948de3624743d79361524c0013/gremlin-server/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/server/handler/HttpGremlinEndpointHandler.java#L190) which is used in [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.HttpChannelizer](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-server/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/server/channel/HttpChannelizer.java), has the below CORS handling already which is adding the requested origin in request header back to the response

```
// handle cors business
if (origin != null) response.headers().set(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, origin);
```

but we want to add more broader CORS and hence we gone ahead and overridden the org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.HttpChannelizer class and the below:

```
private HttpGremlinEndpointHandler httpGremlinEndpointHandler;
```

i.e. HttpChannelizerCustom and HttpGremlinEndpointHandlerCustom

and in [HttpGremlinEndpointHandlerCustom](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/a7181e23421818948de3624743d79361524c0013/gremlin-server/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/server/handler/HttpGremlinEndpointHandler.java#L190) at the same place, we added more broader cors:

```
response.headers().add(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "*");
response.headers().add(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, "GET, POST");
response.headers().add(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, "origin, content-type, accept, X-Requested-With, authorization");
response.headers().add(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS, "true");
```